# Django getting csrf error

Tags: django

I've made a register form, usually it works, but sometimes it gives me the csrf error, after i go back to the register page, it works again:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

This is the register form i've made:

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            email = cd['email']
            password = cd['password1']
            new_user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
                email=email,
                password=password,
            )
            new_user.valid_email = False
            new_user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate your account.'
            message = render_to_string('registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': new_user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(new_user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(new_user),
            })
            new_user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('account:account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    data['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', data)
```

In register.html i am using {% csrf_token %}:

**register.html**

```
<form method="POST" class="m-login__form m-form" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.non_field_errors }}
    {{ user_form.email.errors }}
    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail*" name="email" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    {{ user_form.password1.errors }}
    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Parola*" name="password1">
    </div>
    {{ user_form.password2.errors }}
    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirmati parola*" name="password2">
    </div>
    <div class="m-login__form-action">
        <button id="m_login_signup_submit" class="btn m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air m-login__btn m-login__btn--primary">
            Sign Up
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: please add voew.py also urls.py

Comment: it is there, the register view

Comment: post your urls.py file

Comment: After the registration are you logging in the user ? basically the token changes when a login session changes. So if you are having multiple tabs and logging in one of the tabs, coming back to register, that will give this error.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using csrf middlewares, you need to add csrf permissions to you API, use below given decorators for your API,

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
data = dict()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        email = cd['email']
        password = cd['password1']
        new_user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        new_user.valid_email = False
        new_user.save()
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        subject = 'Activate your account.'
        message = render_to_string('registration/account_activation_email.html', {
            'user': new_user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(new_user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(new_user),
        })
        new_user.email_user(subject, message)
        return redirect('account:account_activation_sent')
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
data['form'] = form
return render(request, 'registration/register.html', data)
```

Hope, this will solve the problem.

Comment: This removes CSRF protection.

Comment: Sorry, I apologize. It doesn't remove the CSRF protection if @csrf_protect decorator is used first. It doesn't make sense to use both of them, but still, I was mistaken. I'll edit your answer with additional info so I can remove the downvote..